# How to write this in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want all the **distinct** players (of a given team), the **leagues they have played in** without duplicate players **ordered by the league start date**. I've the below query return all the players (of a given team) and the leagues they participated in ordered by the start date but as you can see there are duplicates.

```
START t=node(17) 
MATCH player-[:PLAYED_WITH_TEAM]->t-[:CONTESTED_IN]->league 
RETURN player.name, league.startDate, league.name 
ORDER BY league.startDate, player.name
```

result of the above query

[image]

Here is my model

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key to your solution is usage of the `collect` function. Since you want the leagues order by start date, you might need a `with` to split up the query in two parts:

```
START t=node(17) 
MATCH player-[:PLAYED_WITH_TEAM]->t-[:CONTESTED_IN]->league 
WITH player.name as playerName, league.startDate as startDate, league.name as leagueName 
ORDER BY startDate
RETURN player.name, collect(leagueName)
```

Since I don't have your dataset available I could not test the query, so please test yourself.

Comment: I've actually tried this before posting the question. Neoeclipse was giving sytatic errors. But this works in neoshell. A small correction though: player.name should be replaced with playerName in RETURN. Do you know why it is not working in neoeclipse? I will add another SO post for that.

Comment: Here is the neoeclipse related error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972386/why-the-query-works-in-neo4jshell-but-not-in-neoeclipse