# Why the query works in neo4jshell but not in neoclipse?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neoclipse

**QUERY**

START t=node(17) 
MATCH player-[:PLAYED_WITH_TEAM]->t-[:CONTESTED_IN]->league 
WITH player.name as playerName, league.startDate as startDate, league.name as leagueName 
ORDER BY startDate
RETURN playerName, collect(leagueName);

**NeoClipse ERROR**

[image]

**NeoShell Output**

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ START t=node(17)
> MATCH player-[:PLAYED_WITH_TEAM]->t-[:CONTESTED_IN]->league
> WITH player.name as playerName, league.startDate as startDate, league.name as leagueName
> ORDER BY startDate
> RETURN playerName, collect(leagueName);
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| playerName            | collect(leagueName)                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "Satish"              | ["Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 June League","Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 September League"] |
| "Aravind Yarram"      | ["Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 June League","Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 September League"] |
| "Vijay Rasale"        | ["Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 June League","Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 September League"] |
| "Abdul Yaser"         | ["Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 June League","Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 September League"] |
| "Selladurai Velusamy" | ["Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 June League","Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 September League"] |
| "Sandeep"             | ["Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 June League","Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 September League"] |
| "Ashish Abraham"      | ["Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 June League","Sri Bala Bharathi 2012 September League"] |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Swith the `ORDER BY` and `RETURN` clause? Does it work now?

Comment: @tstorms when i change the order, neoclipse complains "Unknown identifier startDate"

Comment: What Neoclipse and Neo4j versions are you using? It might be that Neoclipse is running an older version? There should be new downloads available for 1.9 at https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse